# Struggling with .ToList() returing an EntitySet<...>, not an IList<..>

Tags: linq, entityset

I'm trying to retrieve a list of `Id`'s from a collection that is a few levels deep in an object heirachy. When i try to do a `ToList()`, I keep getting an `EntityList<>` retrieved instead .. which means it's not allowing me to retrieve an instance's `BarId` property because the `EntitySet` is a `Enumerable`, not a single instance object.

```
Foo.Child1 (1 to 1)
Child1.Children2 (0 to many of type Bar)
Bar.BarId int;

IList<Foo> fooList = (from blah blah blah).ToList();

var children2List = (from x in fooList
select x.Child1.Children2).ToList();
```

It keeps returning `children2List` as an `EntitySet<Bar>`, not an `IList<Bar>`. As such, i'm struggling to retrieve the list of `BarId`'s from `children2List`.

please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your can use:

```
var children2List = fooList.SelectMany( x => x.Child1.Children2 ).ToList();
```

This will allow you to do something like:

```
children2List.ForEach( b => b.BarId.Print() );
```

Answer (score 0):

In your query, you turn the whole result into a list, not the individual Children2 sets.
Try

```
var children2List = (from x in fooList
select x.Child1.Children2.ToList()).ToList();
```

This will turn each Children2 into a List.

Comment: That returned a List<List<Bar>> ???? and i'm guessing you're missing a () in the first ToList ...   I still can't get the BarId from the result list....

Comment: Sorry, I thought that was what you wanted.
So you want to flatten the whole thing down to 1 list ?
And Yes, I'm missing a () because I was typing directly in SO :)

Answer (score 0):

`EntitySet<T>` implements `IList<T>`, so you already *are* returning `IList<Bar>`.

Comment: that's what i thought, but it wasn't allowing me to interigate each item. it was also saying i had a collection, not an item.